# On click of the cell get that particular cell value and first column value of that row in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces, I want On click of the cell get that particular cell value and first column value of that row.
Example - I am having following data table

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3    Header 4    Header 5
PDC-All       3.2        3.2          2           3
PDC-1         2.25       3.14         1           2
PDC-2         4.54       5.42         2           2
PDC-3         7.21       8.3          1          **2.5**
OEM-All       2.75       3.05         1           2
OEM-1         3.46       4.21         1.1         1
OEM-2        4.2         4.76         1.8         2.1
```

so when i click 2.5 value , i want to pass 2.5 and PDC-3 value to populate another table on click.
When i click 3.05, i need to pass 3.05 and OEM-All value

Currently my code is

```
<p:dataTable var="record" value="#{transitCycleController.overview}" id="highLevelTable"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{transitCycleController.selectedOverView}" rowKey="#{record.groupName}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" resizableColumns="auto" scrollable="auto" 
                scrollWidth="100%" scrollHeight="150" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                            {RowsPerPageDropdown} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
                            {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})">
```

want to know how to pass these 2 value

Comment: Why not simply make the cell content an p:commandLink and pass in the two values in an actionListener?

Comment: Can you please give me sample example.

Comment: The selection example of the datatable in the PF showcase contains one.  Albeit with a commandButton and not passing the parameters in the actionListener but in a different way

Answer (score 0):

use this in your table,

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{yourbean.function}" update=":form:newdatatable" />
```

so in the listener you put a function, in which you use the parameters to load the new value for the new table.

it will works only if you this attributes on the first datatable.

```
rowKey="#{varfield[0]}" selection="#{yourbean.singlerowitemvar}"
```

so every row will be unique and the current selection will be stored in a dynamic Object[] Item.